# Caching between multiple runs of a single java program

Tags: java, caching

I'm pretty new to the concept of caching, but please bear with me.

I have a java program that is called as part of an OSB proxy that calls it once per request. This program goes externally to get some data, performs a function, then ends (it does not loop or wait, the proxy calls it from the start for every request).

I want to cache the external call, as that data only needs to be fresh within an hour, but am unsure how to set up a cache so that it will persist beyond the different runs of the program

Comment: what kinda data is it? what is a protocol you are using to reach external data? worst case scenario you will have to save it in a file or an external local service providing caching service. It also depends if OSB loads your java class in the same JVM or starts a new one for each invocation

Comment: There are so many options depending on your environement - file, redis, DB, HBase, Zookeeper! Even simpler would be to keep it in memory and don't kill the process?